# Site using old domain name when entering new domain

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have recently tried to move a site I made for a school onto their domain.

When I open http://www.hsbrandwag.co.za it opens my old domain which i was building it on at http://www.freelanceaccounting.co.za

I have updated the wp-options in PHPMYADMIN and I have tried adding

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.hsbrandwag.co.za');
define('WP_SITEURL','http:www.hsbrandwag.co.za');
```

To my wp-config file

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check the db for "wp_options" that you have added your new domain name to where option_name = "site_url" and "home". I think that would be solved your problem. if not then there could be a redirection.